# Can't understand `Exclude<T, U>` in typescript correctly

Tags: typescript, types

There is type definition in typescript:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

We can use it to exclude a type from another type:

```
type AB = 'a' | 'b'
type AC = 'a' | 'c'

type X = Exclude<AB, AC>
```

The type `X` is `b` now.

But when I use the content of `Exclude` directly:

```
type X = AB extends AC ? never : AC;
```

The type `X` is different, it's not `b` anymore, it's `AC`.

I can't understand why it behaves differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly if you replace the content, `X` would be `type X = AB extends AC ? never : AB;`. But that will not give you the same result either.

The reason is that conditional types have a special behavior when it comes to naked type parameters, they distribute over them if they are a union. So when you use `Exclude`, each member of the union is separately put through the condition and the result is unioned. So `Exclude<AC, AB>` is equivalent to:

```
type X = ('a' extends AC ? never : 'a') | ('b' extends AC ? never : 'b')
```

This distributive behavior does not occur with anything except naked type parameters (naked meaning `T` is not used in another type, such as a tuple, an array or as a parameter to another generic type), this is why using the type directly in the condition does not yield the same result. You can read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: Thanks, searching `Distributive conditional types` in the linked page gives me more explanation, I'm clear now