# Typescript: mapped types, strip field from a union

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm trying to create a type mapper `NewRecord<T>` which will strip the `id` type out of `<T>`.
That's how I do it:

```
type NewRecord<T> = {
  [P in Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>]: T[P]
}
```

but, unfortunately, it doesn't play nice with union types. Let me illustrate:

```
interface IRecord {
  id: number
}

interface IBotRecord extends IRecord {
  isBot: true
  cpuCores: 4
}

interface IHumanRecord extends IRecord {
  isBot: false
  isHungry: true
}

type ICreature = IHumanRecord | IBotRecord

type INewBotRecord = NewRecord<IBotRecord>
type INewHumanRecord = NewRecord<IHumanRecord>
type INewCreature = NewRecord<ICreature>

const newHuman:INewHumanRecord = {
  isBot: false,
  isHungry: true // works!
}

const newCreature:INewCreature = {
  isBot: false,
  isHungry: true // does not exist in type NewRecord<ICreature>
}
```

It happens because `keyof` iterates over intersection of types, not unions and that's intended behaviour: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12948

What is the correct way to strip a field from the union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to apply the mapped type for each member of the union. Fortunately conditional types have this exact behavior, they distribute over naked type parameters. This means that the mapped type is applied independently to each member of the union and all results are unioned into the final type. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800639/cant-understand-excludet-u-in-typescript-correctly/52800696#52800696) for more explanations.

In this case the condition in the conditional type can just be `extends any` we don't care about the conditional part we care just about the distribution behavior of the conditional type:

```
type NewRecord<T> = T extends any ? {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>]: T[P]
} : never

type INewCreature = NewRecord<ICreature>
// The above type is equivalent to
type INewCreature = {
    isBot: false;
    isHungry: true;
} | {
    isBot: true;
    cpuCores: 4;
}
const newCreature:INewCreature = {
  isBot: false,
  isHungry: true // works fine
}
```

Comment: Omg it works, so by putting expression inside type conditional I change distribution behaviour! That's a bit surprising :) thank you so much!

Comment: @shlajin one of those TS hidden gems :)

Comment: hmmm... that might be slightly off topic, but if I declare `cpuCores` as optional `cpuCores?`, then after going through `NewRecord<ICreature>` it becomes mandatory... is it something to do with `Exclude`?

Comment: @shlajin Yes, it's off-topic :P. Modifiers are only preserved for homomorphic mapped type. This `Excludes` issue is a known limitation, the compiler doesn't understand that this is homomorphic. If you use `Pick` the problem goes away: `type NewRecord<T> = T extends any ? Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>> : never`